# Is there a specific arc for Sinon in the anime?

Tags: sword-art-online

I'm rewatching the whole *SAO* series and I go to the manga whenever I want to clear things up for the show but I thought about something.

In the Aincrad novels, there are specific chronological Arcs for:

> Silica, Lizbeth, Yui, Sachi

But in the second season, we see Sinon, a "main?" character. But isn't there a specific Arc for her? or some more backstory than what we see in the Anime?

> The fact that she gets scared of guns but in-game she isn't, and her past at the bank.

I couldn't find any Arcs for the characters of the second season so if there are where can I find them or what are they called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The whole *Phantom Bullet* arc **is** Sinon's arc, in the same way the *Fairy Dance* is mostly Leafa's arc, for the most part. Neither character has another side-story outside of these arcs, seeing as most of their past is expanded within them.

In the Light Novels, this is Volumes 5 and 6. Most of what you want to know about Shino/Sinon will be in those two volumes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and pointing out where i could find it in the light novels!

Answer (score 5):

One could say that the two *Phantom Bullet* novels are her arc.

Except for Sachi whose story is shortly summarized, the other characters you named don't appear at all in the original story in the first light novel. They first appear in those character specific stories in the second light novel, which were then integrated with the first novel into the first anime season.

There isn't another Sinon specific story and the anime adapts basically the whole backstory of her from the novels.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on this, i knew some character specific stories werent in the novel but still thanks for the explanation. i accepted the other answer becouse he pointed out in wich exactly it is readdable